# PyTorch differentiable mask

Tags: pytorch

How would I go about blacking out a portion of an image or feature map such that AutoGrad can backprop through the operation?

Specifically I want to black out everything except for n layers of border pixels. So if we consider a single channel of the feature map which looks like:

```
[
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
]
```

I set a constant n=1 so my operation does the following to the input:

```
[
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
]
```

In my case I'd be doing it to a multi channel feature map and all channels would be treated the same way.

If possible, I want to do it in a functional manner.

Comment: Do you want the pattern of the mask to be differentiable? The mask can be considered a step function, so that seems like a non-starter. Unless you somehow smooth the mask, in which case you're essentially just reinventing a convolutional layer, as you say.

Comment: @gspr thanks for jumping on. I'm new to digging around in the guts of PyTorch so this could be simpler than you think. The mask has no parameters. All I want to do is apply it and then calculate a loss. For more context, I will be calculating a L1 loss between the border pixels of the original input image, and the output image (which will have gone through more interesting layers before it reaches the mask). I want the network to preserve the border while having freedom inside the border.

Comment: Also I realised my conv layer idea was bad anyway. I can't tell the weights to do different things to different positions on the feature map, so it wouldn't achieve what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the comments you added, i.e. that you don't need the output to be differentiable wrt. to the mask (said differently, the mask is constant), you could just store the indices of the `1`s in the mask and act only on the corresponding elements of whatever `Tensor` you're considering. Or if you don't want to deal with fancy indexing, you could just keep the mask as a `Tensor` of `0`s and `1`s and do an element-wise multiplication of it with whatever `Tensor` you're considering. Or, if you truly just need to compute a loss along just the border pixels, just extract the first and last row, and first and last column, and avoid double-counting the corners. This latter solution is essentially just the first solution recast in a special case.

To address the question in your comment to my answer:

```
x = torch.tensor([[1.0,2,3],[4,5,6]], requires_grad = True)
print(x[:,0])
```

gives

```
tensor([1., 4.], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
```

, so we see that slicing does not mess with the autograd engine (it's still tracking the contribution to the gradient). It is not too surprising that this works automatically; slicing can be viewed as the (mathematical) function that of *projecting onto a subspace* of R^n, for which it's easy to compute the gradient.

Comment: Thanks! So on the last part, I was under the impression (from experience with TF) that slicing the array (grabbing the border pixels only) would make AutoGrad unhappy. That's why I went with the mask approach. But it sounds like you're saying a can literally do something like this (just top border for simplicity): `input_border = input[:,0,:]; output_border=output[:,0,:]; border_loss = loss_fn(input_border, output_border)` right?

Comment: Ah, I understand. I've edited the answer to address this question.